# PowerShell, the process block, and garbage collection

Tags: powershell, memory, garbage-collection, pipeline

I have an application that reads the contents of lots of (potentially large) text files and updates a BLOB field in a database. There is a function that accepts information about individual files from the pipeline, then reads that file into a string, and sends the string off to the database (very cut down version of this below)

```
function Import-FileToDatabase {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$filePath
    )

    process {
        $contents = Get-LargeFileContents -filePath $filePath
        Import-FileContentsToDb -contents $contents
    }
}
```

The problem is that the $contents variable (string) doesn't drop out of scope and get released for garbage collection at the end of the process block. Instead, it appears that each instance of the string remains on the heap until a much later point. The memory for the pwsh process seems very close to the total file size of all files combined, suggesting that it doesn't release any memory at all until at the very least the pipeline has finished executing.

I've been caught out by assumptions about variable scoping in begin/process/end blocks before, am I right in my suspicion that all variables created within the function persist until the end of the function, including each instance created on each instance of the process block executing? Is there a way of disposing those strings manually in PowerShell? I'm assuming that calling GC.Collect isn't going to work because some reference to the variable still exists somewhere?

Comment: What are you using to read the file content? Your question is too abstract to give a proper answer.

Comment: GC only runs when memory is needed and when data is not linked to any other object.  GC checks the number of external links to the object and will only delete when no object are linked.

Comment: You can try to call the GC manually as a test. Although I don't recommend making a habit out of running the GC manually, there are use cases where it's a fine solution (just do it every x iterations). Powershell can be very weird when it comes to garbage collection (to the point that even running remove-variable wasn't enough unless I'd run [GC]::Collect()

Comment: thanks @bluuf, I hadn't considered using the remove-variable cmdlet, I have a feeling I'll need to combine it with GC.Collect because I'm not sure the reference to the variable is being released on each iteration of the process block. Still seems like a mystery as to how it instantiates and releases variables - as I say my best guess is that each instance is maintained until the cmdlet finishes